# Evaluate $\lim_{s \rightarrow 1^{-}} \frac{\Gamma(b-as)}{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)}$, for $a,b>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, integral-transforms, mellin-transform

I encountered the following as a result of a Mellin-transform:

$$
\frac{\Gamma(b-as)}{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)},\quad b>0,\ 0 < a,\text{Re}(s) < 1
$$
where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the gamma function.

Because of the restriction that the real part of $s$ should be within $0$ and $1$, I am curious as to whether the following limit exist and if it exists, what is its value in terms of $a$ and $b$.

$$
\lim_{s\rightarrow 1^{-}} \frac{\Gamma(b-as)}{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)}
$$

Direct substitution might lead to something like:
$$
\lim_{s\rightarrow 1^{-}} \frac{\Gamma(b-as)}{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)} = \Gamma(b-a)
$$
knowing $\Gamma(0) = \Gamma(1) = 1$. Still I am not sure if I'm doing this right.

**EDIT:** Additional context.

From Lemma 1.11 (page 44) of Kibas etal's *Theory and Applications of Fractional Differential Equations* it states:

> For $\alpha > 0$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}\ (|\arg(-z)| < \pi)$ the following relation holds:
> $$ E_{a,b}(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma - i\infty}^{\gamma + i\infty} \frac{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)}{\Gamma(b-as)}(-z)^{-s}\,\text{d}s$$
> where the path of integration separates all the poles at $s = -k$ ($k \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$) to the left and all the poles at $s = n + 1$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$) to the right.

The author then followed-up with a remark that the Mellin-transform of the function $E_{a,b}(-z)$is given by
$$
\mathcal{M}\left[E_{a,b}(-z)\right](s) = \frac{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)}{\Gamma(b-as)}\quad (0 < \text{Re}(s) < 1)
$$
immediately follows from this lemma. The function $E_{a,b}(z)$ above is the well-known *Mittag-Leffler type function* defined as
$$
E_{a,b}(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{\Gamma(an + b)}\quad (\text{Re}(a) > 0, b\in\mathbb{C})
$$

Thus, follows my question of curiosity.

Comment: What is $x$ in the last equation ?

Comment: ah, sorry about that, editing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near $s = 1$, $\Gamma(s)$ is bounded and $\Gamma(1 - s) = \frac{1}{1 - s} + O(1) ,$ so, if $\Gamma(b - a s)$ does not have a pole at $s = 1$, (equivalently, $\Gamma$ does not have a pole at $b - a$) we have $$\lim_{s \to 1} \frac{\Gamma(b - a s)}{\Gamma(s) \Gamma(1 - s)} = 0 .$$ Now, the poles of $\Gamma$ are all simple and occur exactly at the nonpositive integers $-n$, and their respective residues are $\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$, so if $a - b \in \Bbb Z_{\geq 0}$, the limit is
$$\lim_{s \to 1} \frac{\Gamma(b - a s)}{\Gamma(s) \Gamma(1 - s)} = \frac{(-1)^{a - b}}{a \cdot (a - b)!} ,$$ and for other values of $a, b$, the limit is zero.

Comment: Is there are way to extend the second equality for the case $a-b\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$? What i mean is, can we replace $(a-b)!$ with $\Gamma(a-b + 1)$ if we take $a-b\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and still the result holds?

Comment: If $a - b$ is not nonnegative integer, then $\lim_{s \to 1} \Gamma(b - a s)$ is bounded near $s = 1$, so the first case applies, i.e., the limit is zero.

Comment: Ah i see. Thank you @Travis Willse for this.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\Gamma(b - a s)}{\Gamma(s)\, \Gamma(1 - s)}= \Gamma (b-a)(1-s)\left(1+a  \psi ^{(0)}(b-a)(1-s)+O\left((s-1)^2\right) \right)$$

For approximations, the $[n+1,n]$ Padé approximants $P_n$ are quite good. Form example, using $t=(1-s)$
$$P_1=\Gamma (b-a)\, t \,\,\frac {1+\frac{1}{6}  \left(3 a \psi ^{(0)}(b-a)+\frac{\frac{\pi ^2}{a}-3 a
   \psi ^{(1)}(b-a)}{\psi ^{(0)}(b-a)}\right)t }{1+\frac{\pi ^2-3 a^2 \left(\psi ^{(0)}(b-a)^2+\psi ^{(1)}(b-a)\right)}{6 a   \psi ^{(0)}(b-a)}t }$$ is $O(t^5)$.

Comment: What does $\psi^{(0)}$ stand for?

Comment: @rxs2p0. The digamma function. In fact, there are very nice *approximations* of this function. I developed some of them for numerical considerations. If you are interested, I can add them here. Cheers :-)

Comment: Wow. Please do @Claude Leibovici. If you have some links for a comprehensive and detailed resources, I would highly appreciate it.